# Opening TLS connection with ‘gnutls-cli --x509cafile /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem -p 443 stable.melpa.org’...failed

Tags: init-file, gnutls

I am making a new Emacs config an in it, I have the following lines

```
(with-eval-after-load 'tls
  (push "/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem" gnutls-trustfiles)
  (setf gnutls-verify-error nil)
  (setf tls-checktrust t))

;; Initialize package sources
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             ("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
             ))
(package-initialize)

(unless package-archive-contents
 (package-refresh-contents))
```

The issue is that the connection to Melpa servers fails with the following error

```
Failed to download ‘melpa’ archive.
Opening TLS connection to ‘stable.melpa.org’...
Opening TLS connection with ‘gnutls-cli --x509cafile /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem -p 443 stable.melpa.org’...failed
Opening TLS connection with ‘gnutls-cli --x509cafile /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem -p 443 stable.melpa.org --protocols ssl3’...failed
Opening TLS connection to ‘stable.melpa.org’...failed
Package refresh done
```

Furthermore, when I manually test the following command at the command line, it seems to work

```
gnutls-cli --x509cafile /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem -p 443 --no-strict-tofu stable.melpa.org
Processed 128 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'stable.melpa.org:443'...
Connecting to 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443'...
- Certificate type: X.509
- Got a certificate list of 3 certificates.
- Certificate[0] info:
```

While, the following command fails the checks

```
gnutls-cli --x509cafile /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem -p 443 stable.melpa.org
...
- Status: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.
*** PKI verification of server certificate failed...
*** Fatal error: Error in the certificate.
```

How can I make the Emacs config work? My understanding is that it fails due to certificate check errors (self-signed certificates).

Answer (score 0):

If adding `--no-strict-tofu` makes the `gnutls-cli` invocation work, then customize `tls-program` to include that flag.

Longer term it would be better to get an Emacs with builtin GnuTLS support, that tends to handle these issues much better.

Comment: Should I compile it with a certain config flag set to get builtin GnuTLS support?

Comment: It's autodetected if you have the GnuTLS headers, they're usually in a package called "gnutls-dev" or similar